# How to run powershell command via cmd.

Tags: powershell, cmd

This works perfect in CMD:

C:\>powershell.exe write-host -Foreground Red "hello"

But I have problem running this command:

C:\>powershell.exe [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.1.100")

I've already tried adding the -command  options but still getting an error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with address in single quotes

```
powershell.exe [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('192.168.1.100')
```